# Regex pattern help (I almost have it, just need a bit of expertise to finish it)

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect

I need to match two cases

```
js/example_directory/example_name.js
```

and

```
js/example_directory/example_name.js?12345
```

(where 12345 is a digit string of unknown length and the directory can be limitless in depth or not exist at all)

I need to capture in both cases everything between `js/` and `.js`
and **if** `?` exists capture *the digit string* after `?`

This is what I have so far

```
^js/(.*).js\??(\d+)?
```

This works except it also captures

```
js/example_directory/example_name.js12345
```

I want the regex to ignore that. Any suggestions?
Thank you all!

Test your patterns [here](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/)

**Answer:**
Using Gumbo's information my final rewrite rule is as follows.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^\d*$
 RewriteRule ^js/(.*)\.js$ js.php?f=$1.js&v=%0 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: What exactly do you use? mod_rewrite (`RewriteRule`), mod_alias (`RedirectMatch`) or what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[mod_rewrite’s `RewriteRule` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) does only test the URI path and not the query. So using a rule like the following does already match both URIs:

```
RewriteRule ^js/(.*)\.js$ …
```

If you now want to test the query too, you need to use an additional [`RewriteCond`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^\d*$
RewriteRule ^js/(.*)\.js$ …
```

The match of the last successful `RewriteCond` can be referred to with `%n`, so in case of the whole match `%0` or in this case even just `%{QUERY_STRING}` directly.

Comment: Gumbo, is there a way to make the rewrite condition, optional. Like this; if query exists be numeral, if does not exist proceed anyway.

Comment: I also don't understand the comment you made about %n if you would please offer more information on that I would be grateful.

Comment: @Mohammad: Using `^\d*$` does already allow an empty query; but if, it needs to be numeric. And `%n` (where *n* is a number in 0–9) is used to reference the match of the whole regular expression (`%0`) or just the match of a specific group (`%n` is the match of the n-th group).

Comment: Gumbo, thank you! I've updated the question with the final rule I used. Please see if there is any need for improvement. And thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

Include the whole querystring pattern, including the ? in one conditional match.

```
^js/(.*).js(\?\d+)?
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as regular expressions go - you can use the `(?:)` (non capture grouping) to make the \?(\d+) as a chunck, optional like so:

```
^js/(.*).js(?:\?(\d+))?
```

You really don't >need< to use the `?:` (non capture) portion, but *if you don't*, back references will be changed - 1 will point at the filename, 2 will point at `?1234` and 3 will be `1234`